# Git : How to have fork-only file

Tags: git

I want to contribute to a free software on GitHub, I have my own fork on GitLab and would like to have my own .gitlab-ci.yml for deployment pipeline.

How can my fork own files that aren't part of upstream ?

Thanks

Comment: On your fork you can create a branch and do whatever you like with it.

Answer (score 0):

Create two branches: one for code that will be offered in pull requests and the other to run your own tests. Let's call the branches `dev` and `tests`.

Configure Gitlab to not run CI jobs in branches that don't have the file `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

In the branch `dev` you edit, add, commit and push code. Then switch to branch `test`, create `.gitlab-ci.yml`, add it and commit. Merge branch `dev` to `test` to bring changed code. Push the branch `test` and watch CI jobs.

Something like this:

```
git branch dev  # from the current branch…
git branch test  # …perhaps from `master`

git checkout dev
vim code  # edit and save
git add -A .
git commit -m "Commit message"
git push -u origin dev  # `origin` is your fork

git checkout test
vim .gitlab-ci.yml
git add .gitlab-ci.yml
git commit -m "Add .gitlab-ci.yml"
git merge dev
git push -u origin test
```

If there are errors fix them in `dev` and merge again. In such situation I usually don't afraid of removing the previous merge commit, amending `dev` and force-push both branches but let's do it in slow correct way:

```
git checkout dev
vim code  # Fix
git add
git commit
git push origin

git checkout test
git merge dev
git push
```

Every time you change code in `dev` merge it to `test`, push and wait for the CI jobs to finish. Then create the next pull request from `dev` to the upstream repository.